# Send large number of notifications

Tags: php, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have 10.000 deviceid , and I want to send push notifications .

My question whats the best way to save and retreive these devieceid ?

Im  thinking to save them in text file and seperat them by semicolon ;

Then when I want to send message create array and split them by semicolon and making loop for array elements "deviceid"

And send notification for each device .

My question this is good solution ?

Or it will affect the memory and speed specially there are thousands of deviceid , also I have seen on the net some people faced problem when they send large number of emails ... sms .. etc ,

How to avoid it in case of notifications

Answer (score 0):

When you will loop through each device id your speed will get slow.
Try to simple it as much as possible
Check for send messages to all at once will be good 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi how r u How I can send message to all at once ?